# PowerShell converts html tags "<" and ">" to "&lt;" and "&gt;"

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to generate a HTML report using powershell. I use ConvertTo-html & is working fine. However, I need to pass some values with HTML tags such as <.br.> to the cell values in the HTML table. 
Unfortunately the tags are converted to "&.lt.;" and "&.gt.;" when generating the html file.
I tried to avoid this with [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlDecode and also by -replace function. But none is working.
Is there any other way to avoid this conversion?

## This is the code I used

```
`$table1 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable  
$table1 .Columns.Add("Parameter","string")  
$table1 .Columns.Add("Value","string")  

$row1 = $table1.NewRow()
```

..............
..............

```
$row1.Value = "Some Value here <BR>"  

$table1 | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors | ConvertTo-html  -Body $BodyText >> "$filepath\$name.html"`
```

=================================================================

Comment: could you post the snippet you tried please ?

Comment: I updated the post with the code. The issue here is, I want to add a line break to the $row1.Value. But it will just display the html tag instead of line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Added a string tag replacement to the last line as below.

```
$table1 | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors | ConvertTo-html  -Body "<H2> Header Text </H2>" | foreach { $PSItem -replace "-linebreak-", "<BR>" } >> "$filepath\$name.html"
```